# Роз'яснення щодо слів із суфіксом -івн-

Tags: значення-слів

В одному з дописів на цьому форумі знайшов посилання на статтю пані [Кочерги](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) ["Мовознавчі репресії 1933 року"](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n35texts/kocherha.htm). В ній мене зацікавив цей уривок:

> Вилучення слів із суфіксом -івн- має наслідком нашу неспроможність
>   відрізняти прикметники на позначення активної здатности (*рятівний,
>   коливний, фільтрівний, йонізівний*) та призначення (*рятувальний,
>   коливальний, фільтрувальний, йонізувальний*), не кажучи вже про те, що
>   їх часто заступають активні дієприкметники, що від часу їхнього
>   примусового запровадження заполонили мову, наче бур’ян.

Але я так і не зрозумів різницю між:

```
рятівний    - рятувальний
коливний    - коливальний
фільтрівний - фільтрувальний
йонізівний  - йонізувальний
```

і як їх можуть заступити активні дієприкметники?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Детальний опис ріжницї від посібника [Євгенії Чак](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) «Чи правильно ми говоримо?» на прикладї слів: *рятівний* – *рятувальний*.

**[Рятува́льний, рятівни́й](//chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/r#ryatuvalnyi-ryativnyi); рятува́льник, рятівни́к.**

> **Рятувальний** означає *спеціально створений для рятування*, *призначений для рятування*.
>
> *Сержант з аеродромної обслуги роздавав пасажирам гумові рятувальні жилети*. (П. Загребельний.) *Під нами океан, і стюардеса Соня просить пасажирів ознайомитися з технікою одягання рятувального костюма. Це на той випадок, якщо літак упаде в океан*. (Л. Дмитерко.) *Майстерно кріпили рятувальні шлюпки, закривали трюми, відкачували воду з кают і службових приміщень*. (З журналу.) *Вони хутко вибігли на палубу, де висіли шлюпки, а на сітчастих бортах — рятувальні круги*. (Петро Панч.) *Сьогодні мусив повернутися з відрядження батько. Для мене він — немов рятувальний круг у морі*. (В. Дрозд.) *Рятувальна експедиція вдруге вивозила людей. […] А шхуна поквапливо лягає у дрейф і спускає рятувального човна*. (З. Тулуб.)

> **Рятівний** і його синоніми **рятівничий**, **рятунковий** мають значення *той, що приносить порятунок*.
>
> *Отже, як не крути, а головою муру не пробʼєш. Залишалося тільки одне, чекати порятунку від Яринки, чекати пʼятниці і рятівного сигналу.* (В. Козаченко.) *Василь Васильович, мов крізь сон, відчув укол, рятівна рідина влилась під шкіру, і йому стало легше*. (Л. Дмитерко.)

> А от у реченні *розсікаючи хвилі, швидко мчав до баркаса рятівний катер* без контексту важко визначити точно семантику словосполучення *рятівний катер*. Якщо йдеться про катер, спеціально призначений для рятування на воді, слід було б ужити слово *рятувальний*. Але якщо автор хотів сказати, що катер (будь-якого призначення — чи для перевезення пасажирів, чи для попередження нещасних випадків) ніс порятунок комусь, хто перебував у небезпеці, доречно вжити словосполучення *рятівний катер*.
>
> В усному мовленні, як зазначають українські словники, слово *рятівний* вживається також у значенні *призначений для рятування*. На це натрапляємо і в художній літературі. Наприклад: *підняти всіх жителів узбережжя для рятівних* (правильніше: *рятувальних*) *робіт на бродах* або в такому ж значенні, тільки з синонімом слова *рятівний — рятівничий*: *інженер зорганізував рятівничу команду з дачників*.
>
> У літературній мові, писемній і усній, слід уникати таких лексичних замін, бо все-таки ці слова дещо відрізняються значенням: адже не завжди і не всякі *рятувальні* дії (тобто дії, спрямовані на здійснення порятунку) виявляються *рятівними* (тобто такими, що справді приносять порятунок).

*… далї опис ріжницї між **рятувальник** та **рятівник**, суть майже та сама.*

---

Щодо дїєприкметників, то вони [не притаманні](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%92%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96), як в московській, українській мові. Тому при змозї бажано їх уникати.

Comment: Є слова діагоналізовний, спростовний, читний, що позначають таких, що можна відповідно діагоналізувати, спростувати, читати. А чи не знаєте як сказати "той, якого можна врятувати" одним словом?

Comment: savable. В англійській зазвичай утворюються за допомогою -able

Comment: Ох, афіксоїд (чи складне слово?), в сьому анґлїйська гнучкіша. Не дуже допомогло, досї не маю гадки. Можливо, чисто за морфемікою, _порятув[a]ний_ чи _врятувний_. _Врятувна людина_, _врятувний потопаючий_ — як на мене, звучить непогано, хоча доволі незвично. Що думаєте?

Comment: Так, добре! Тільки, мабуть, потопельник.

Comment: Так, мабуть, хоч і [[по](http://sum.in.ua/s/potopeljnyk)][топельник](http://sum.in.ua/s/topeljnyk) наразї це хто вже втопився, себто вже точно не врятувнї. В нас окрім наросткових проблем, ще є приросткові. Добре постаралися совєти, титанова праця аж нїяк. І наші институти не дуже намагаютця сього виправити. Зустрів ще [тонучий](http://sum.in.ua/s/tonuchyj).

Comment: Думаю, іноді, таки не варто соромитися і брати (вже існуючі) запозичення. Такі слова, як читабельний, жувабельний - утворені українськими коренями "чит" і "жув" із додаванням англійського слова "able" Більшість людей може й не здогадуватися, що ці слова наполовину іншомовні. Отже людина, яку можна врятувати є рятувабельною. До речі є ще давнє таке слово, як "тонюк". Зараз уже майже не вживається, але люди з таким прізвищем точно є. Позначає людина, яка тонула, але врятувалася/була врятована.

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо дуже цікаво про "тонюк". Щодо *читабельний*, гадаю не варто вживати запозичений сууфікс коли є власний словотвірний апарат. *Читабельний* - *читний*. Вважаю, що варто його відновити і розвинути, щоб він став природнім для носіїв мови.

Answer (score -2):

« як сказати "той, якого можна врятувати" одним словом?»

Англійському -able відповідає українське -овуваний, тому **«врято́вуваний»**.
 *(Так, це дієприкметник від «врятовувати», і так, дієприкметники в українській мові існують. Їх відсутність — міф, розповсюджуваний сучасними неуками з дипломом філолога, схильними записувати в «суржик» будь-яку українську мову від часів Котляревського і до початку 90-х. Радянський період хіба що дещо розширив практику застосування дієприкметників, але вони існували в українській мові ще до того, як їх почали широко вживати, наслідуючи російські зразки).*

Пропоноване тут «врятуваний» граматично неможливе: «врятува́ти» має наголос на суфіксі (на відміну від, наприклад, «стве́рджувати» чи «зни́щувати»), тому пасивний дієприкметник від нього утворюється з переносом наголосу на «у», яке походить від ненаголошеного «о» й, отримавши наголос, набуває вигляду «о». В даному випадку, закономірна форма — «врятований», але воно позначає не можливість врятувати, а вже здійснений успішний порятунок. Чи малось на увазі «вря́туваний» від неіснуючого «вря́тувати»? :)

Comment: Як щодо *врятовний* за аналалогією з [діагоналізовний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)

Comment: Якби ви знайшли якесь джерело для підтвердження вашої думки про *-овуваний*, якусь статтю чи приклади класиків.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainain Language.SE! Щиро кажучи, мені не дуже очевидно, як цей допис відповідає на запитання.

Comment: Перепрошую за відповідь, яка мала б бути насправді коментарем — я тут новенький, не знайшов кнопки «коментувати» під коментарем, який містив питання, на яке я тут спробував відповісти.

Comment: @PYPY, на жаль, тут можливість коментувати (мається на увазі — чужі дописи; свої завжди можна) надається лише після досягнення користувачем рейтингу в 50 (мені особисто такі обмеження не подобаються, але ми обрали шлях приєднатися до існуючої мережі StackExchange, а не робити свій сайт з нуля, тож ми не можемо це змінити). На щастя, Ви вже маєте аж 65 рейтингу, тож уже можете і відповідати, і коментувати, і розмовляти в чаті, і багато чого. Про всяк випадок — кнопка коментування виглядає [так](//i.imgur.com/zsbDoSJ.png). Ну і в будь-якому разі, радий, що Ви приєдналися. В нас тут обмаль людей.

Answer (score -2):

Щодо основного питання. Оскільки слова з суфіксом -івн- було обмежено в правах майже сотню років тому, нам складно точно відтворити той зміст, що вкладався в них тоді. «Рятувальний» — той, що призначений для рятування (необов'язково при цьому задіюваний для порятунку — рятувальний костюм може пролежати в крамниці, доки його миші не з'їдять, рятувальна бригада може пити пиво, поки в річці хтось тоне). «Рятуючий» — такий, що безпосередньо рятує. «Рятівний» лежить десь на перетині цих значень, або близько до того — пов'язаний безпосередньо з рятунком. Мені важко сказати, чи є рятувальне коло рятівним, коли висить на складі, але кинуте в воду й піймане тонучою людиною, воно точно є рятівним — бо рятує її.

Або ще «гальмівний шлях» (шлях, який машина проходить під час гальмування) — не «гальмувальний» (бо це не засіб для гальмування взагалі), як і не «гальмуючий». Хоча про «гальмівну систему» також можна сказати й «гальмувальна» (хоча я б віддав перевагу «гальмівній» як лаконічнішому й елегантнішому варіанту), і навіть «гальмуюча» (безпосередньо тоді, коли вона гальмує).

А тепер яка ситуація складається нині: ми вивчили, що дієприкметники — кака, тому всіляко уникаємо їх, але гідної заміни для них не знаємо, зловживаючи або прикметниками на -увальний, або підрядними реченнями, що не набагато краще за зловживання дієприкметниками.

Comment: І ще одне. Дві відповіді від одного користувача на одне і те саме  запитання мають сенс лише тоді, коли вони обидві відповідають на запитання, але з принципово різних точок зору. У даному випадку, на мою думку, має сенс скласти обидва ваші дописи разом.

Comment: Так, я згоден із bytebuster. У даноми випадку було би доречніше відредагувати («edit») першу відповідь, зробивши її «вмістилищем» усіх Ваших думок, а не створювати окрему відповідь під тим же запитанням. Ви, в принципі, й зараз можете це зробити, натиснувши «edit» на старішій відповіді, а потім «delete» на новішій.

Comment: Щодо активних дієприкметників, то зверніть увагу на цю статтю, там і про рос мову цікаво написано [Активні дієприкметники в українській літературній мові: уживати чи ні?](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/handle/123456789/42899)

Comment: По-моєму, боротьба з дієприкметниками як самоціль — початково хибна задача. Навіть авторка статті визнає, що ці «невластиві» слова глибоко вкоренилися в українську мову. Якщо так, то чи справді вони їй настільки невластиві — адже ми вже не можемо їх позбутися, не спотворивши зміст неточними синонімами й не перетворюючи кожне друге речення на складнопідрядне пекло.